# Destroying an InputMethodService the moment it is created

Tags: java, android, exception, android-input-method, android-securityexception

I have a subclass of `InputMethodService` which should only be created if the user is in my app so if the user enables it through the Android language settings the keyboard should be immediately deactivated and changed back to the default keyboard. My subclass is like so:

```
public class CustomIME extends InputMethodService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // do onCreate() stuff and find current activity

        if(currentActivity != myActivity){
            switchBackToDefaultKeyboard(defaultKeyboard);
        }
    }

    public void switchBackToDefaultKeyboard(IME ime) {
        try {
            switchInputMethod(ime.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            DebugLog.e("Switching failed"); // this always fails when called from onCreate()
        }
    }
}
```

Like I write in the comments the `InputMethodService.switchInputMethod()` method will always throw an exception if I am trying to switch the keyboard from within `onCreate()`.

The exception message is:

`java.lang.SecurityException: Using null token requires permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`